# Jquery click function not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im trying to generate a element dynamically and bind the element to a click event using the below code..Everything works fine but the click event is not being triggered when I click datasource.

```
function create_datasource_facet(facetcount){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(facetcount))
        $('#filters').append('<div id="datafacet"></div>')
        $.each(facetcount,function(index,value){
                console.log(value);
                console.log(index);
                $('#datafacet').append('<br>')
                $('#datafacet').append('<div id="datasource">' + index + '[' + value + ']  </div>')
                //$('#datafacet').append('<br>')

        })

$(document).on('click','#datssource',function(){ alert('datasource clicked')})

}
```

Comment: Spelling mistake in `$(document).on('click','#datssource',function()`

Comment: also note that even though javascript has ASI, strict browsers can make problems with that. so better close everything with semicolons just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the ID value here:

```
$(document).on('click','#datssource',function(){ alert('datasource clicked')})
----------------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

You've misspelt `#datasource` in your click event handler.

---

One thing to be aware of is that you're potentially trying to append multiple elements with the id '#datasource'. IDs should be unique, so you're probably better off making this into a class `.datasource`.

Comment: @isherwood this is true. Removed that, and added in a note about duplicate IDs which he is likely to run into

Comment: I didn't catch the duplicate IDs. Well spotted. OP could also increment the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

`click` Event on `#datasource` not `#datssource`

```
function create_datasource_facet(facetcount){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(facetcount))
        $('#filters').append('<div id="datafacet"></div>')
        $.each(facetcount,function(index,value){
                console.log(value);
                console.log(index);
                $('#datafacet').append('<br>')
                $('#datafacet').append('<div id="datasource">' + index + '[' + value + ']  </div>')
                //$('#datafacet').append('<br>')

        })

$(document).on('click','#datasource',function(){ alert('datasource clicked')})

}
```

Comment: You've misspelled the ID value, too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Think that your code is load before the document is loaded.

try it

```
$('#datssource').on('click',function(){ alert('datasource clicked')})

}
```